# "cannot unpack non-iterable int object" from OrderedDict

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to populate a list using a list comprehension but im getting this error, even though I'm trying to unpack an ordered dictionary, not an int.

cannot unpack non-iterable int object

```
player_drives = OrderedDict({
    entry[0] : entry[10]
    for entry in stats_drives.league_dash_pt_stats.data['data']
    if entry[0] not in player_ids_ignore and entry[0] in player_ids
    })
df['drives per attempt'] = [data / player_fgas[player_id] for player_id, data in player_drives]
```

The error is occurring on the last line included.

Comment: Don't you need a player_drives.items() ? If you just do player_drives that pulls all the keys.

Comment: You aren't trying to unpack a dict, you are trying to unpack the keys of a dict: `player_id, data in player_drives`. The keys are `int` objects here, so if you do `list(player_drives)` you'll get a list of `int` objects. You likely meant `... for player_id, data in player_drives.items()]`... In the future, you **really** need to do some basic debugging before posting a question here on stack overflow. At the very least, you could have unrolled your list comprehension into the equivalent for-loop, and put some prints in there to see what is actually happening

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?